# Most common/idiotproof way to catch invalid input

Tags: c++, char, cin

I am getting into c++ right now, and right now I want to know the most common/best way to catch invalid input.  I would love answers to this wide open question, but my more specific question is as follows.

I want a char from the user.  If the char is 'y' then it will repeat, if it is 'n' then the program will close.  If I enter multiple chars then it will repeat as many times as chars e.g. I enter 'hello' it will show my output 5 times.  I assume that it reads each char and goes through the whole loop then reads the next char in line.  How can I get it to show up just one time?

```
bool valid = 0;
while(valid)
{

...

    bool secValid = 0;
    while(secValid == 0)
    {
        cout << "To enter another taxable income type 'y': \n\n";
        char repeat = NULL;
        cin >> repeat;
        if(repeat == 'y')
        {
            valid = 0;
            secValid = 0;
            system("cls");
        }else if(repeat == 'n')
        {
            return;
        }else
        {
            secValid = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oops, I had changed them from constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::getline()`:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
if (line == "y") {
   // handle yes
}
else if (line == "n") {
   // handle no
}
else {
   // handle invalid input
}
```

Comment: You **always** need to check that the input was successful: `if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) { ... }`

Comment: What input is an example of when it would be unsuccessful?  If the user hit return? With nothing typed

Comment: `std::getline()` fails if there are no characters, e.g., when using Ctrl-D (UNIX) or Ctrl-Z (Windows). Since the `std::string` is unchanged when the input fails you'd have an infinite loop. For formatted inputs, e.g., integers there is more potential for failure.

Answer (score 3):

You could structure it something like this:

```
while(true) {
    cout << "Repeat (y/n)? ";
    string line;
    if(!getline(cin, line))
        break; // stream closed or other read error
    if(line == "y") {
        continue;
    } else if(line == "n") {
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
    }
}
```

Example session:

```
Repeat (y/n)? y
Repeat (y/n)? foo
Invalid input.
Repeat (y/n)? n
```

Here we use `std::getline` to get a whole line of input, instead of getting one character at a time.

Comment: You need to check after `std::getline()` that the read was successful, e.g., `if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

use `std::getline` from the `<string>` header to read a *line* of input into a `std::string`

Answer (score 2):

Also when checking string for "y" or "n" is good practise to use upcased string instead. For example

```
std::string YES = "Y";
std::string NO = "N";
...
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), std::toupper);
if (line == YES)
{
    ...
}
else if (line == NO)
{
    ..
```

.
}

Comment: Do I need to import something to use transform?

Comment: Yes, you should include <algorithm> module. transform function applies unary (or binary) function to iterable object and writes result to another iterable object.

Comment: Note that this use of `toupper()` can lead to crashes: if `char` is signed, using it with non-ASCII values leads to undefined behavior! You need to use something like `char my_toupper(unsigned char c) { return std::toupper(c); }`. Also, you need to check after the read that it was successful.